# Trying to teach myself RoR through building a simple app. where do I start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all, forgive the newbie question -- I won't begrudge downvoters.

What I have in mind is 3 views.

```
A main index page. 
A sub index page where the user can drill down to a sub index and
A page that houses content relating to the particular item chosen from the sub-index
```

Should I create the models first or controllers or views?  As a very new programmer, should I use scaffolding?

The more concrete the answers to this question the better or if there are other resources with specific executable steps you can point me to, that would be great.

Comment: I recommend searching in Google, or StackOverflow, or *somewhere*, for "rails tutorial."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ (click on the book link at the top) by the time you get done you'll have what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this will help a lot.